# Click events doesn't bubble up in RecyclerView

Tags: android, events, android-view

I'm wondering why `click` events doesn't bubble up if I click inside a `RecyclerView`.

My scenario uses a simple `RecyclerView` to show some `TextView`s, while its parent `View` has an `OnClickListener` registered to perform some action if someone clicks into the view.
If I click on e.g. a `TextView` the click event bubbles properly up to the parent. But if I click onto the `RecyclerView` the click doesn't bubble up.
The weird thing is, that if I set an `OnClickListener` directly on the `RecyclerView` it is also never fired. I assume that is the root of all evil.

So, why does my `RecyclerView` don't receive any click events? Why doesn't its parent receive any click events?

Hierarchy looks like this:

```
- View (has an OnClickListener)  <- Why no clicks?
    - RecyclerView (clickable=false)
        - TextView
        - TextView
        ....
```

I experimented with `setFocusable()` and `setClickable()`, but without luck.

PS: My current solution sets an `OnClickListener` on each `TextView` inside the `RecyclerView` and uses `getParent()` to propagate the click to the parent view using `performClick()` manually.

Comment: If i am not missing something, you are correct. The RecycleView doesn't bubble events.

Answer (score 0):

I use the special class handler for `RecyclerView`, the `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener`. I can be added from the consuming class. Here is the default implementation of the handler class:

recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener( new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            //Put your code here.
            //Called 2 times per touch, on pressdown and on release.

            return false; //true will disable scroll view. 
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            setDefaultBottomBar();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
```